# Remove class after sort in jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two connected jQuery UI sort lists. I am attempting to remove the `selected` class immediately after it is dropped into a different list. So if I drop an item from the list on the left into the list on the right, the `selected` class should be removed so it does not remain highlighted.

I have tried putting `$('ul').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');` inside of the `stop, beforeStop, update, out` sortable methods but none of them seem to delete the class after it has been dropped.

Some other things I have tried is inside of the `stop` method adding `info.item.removeClass('selected')` but it does absolutely nothing. What am I missing?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bb4nkpyp/2/).

Below is the code in its entirety.

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
    revert: 0,
    helper: function (e, item) {
        var helper = $('<li/>');
        if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    stop: function (e, info) {
        $('ul').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Multi-select Drag</p>
<p>
    <kbd>Click</kbd> to select individual items<br />
    <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to select multiple items
</p>
<br />

<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `li.selected` element is still being dragged when `stop` is called, so it's not actually a child of the `ul` element. To fix this, reference it in the event object:

```
$(e.toElement).removeClass('selected');
```

To handle multidrag (deselect all elements when finished dragging multiple elements):

```
info.item.data("multidrag").removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: Thank you this works, I like it better than the timer solution.

Comment: I just noticed one issue though that I did not mention. If I select multiple items it does not remove all classes it will only remove a single class.

Comment: I took another look, and there's actually a simpler way to handle multidrag, just do `info.item.data("multidrag").removeClass('selected');`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'selected' class inside a setTimeout() function.

Please see the code below,

http://jsfiddle.net/bb4nkpyp/3/

```
stop: function (e, info) {       
        setTimeout(function(){ $('ul').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected'); }, 10);

        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this does the trick and I had thought about this. I was hesitant because I was unsure if there could be an edge case where it is not removed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/hjyv9yv2/1/

```
var lastSelected = 0, list;
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
list = $(this).parent();
if (lastSelected !== list.index()){
    $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
}
if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
} else {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
}
lastSelected = list.index();
```

}).

If the user click on the another list, remove the 'selected' classname in both lists